# How can update the badge number on app icon of Motorola and google nexus devices in android?

Tags: android

Want to update the badge count in android app icon, we successfully updated on the Samsung, LG Sony etc devices, but **can't update the badge on Motorola and Google nexus device**. Can you please suggests any solution for the same?

Answer (score 2):

I know that this question is from 7 months ago, but anyway: recently, I was searching about badges in Android Apps, and I found that you are not able do it in Stock devices (like Motorola and Nexus devices).

Take a look at this [link](https://forums.androidcentral.com/moto-g-2015/620248-how-make-unread-count-badges-work-motorola-moto-g-2015-facebook-wapp-icons.html).